# (shell) How to remove strings from one file which can be found in another file?

Tags: shell

**file1.txt**

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
```

**file2.txt**

```
DDDD
cccc
aaaa
```

**result**

```
bbbb
eeee
```

If it could be case insensitive it would be even more great!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried any thing.  And an os/scripting engine is a good thing to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` can match patterns read from a file, and print out all lines NOT matching that pattern. Can match case insensitively too, like

```
grep -vi -f file2.txt file1.txt
```

Excerpts from the man pages:

```
SYNOPSIS
   grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
   grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]

   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one  per  line.  The empty file contains zero
          patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)ns zero
          patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
   -i, --ignore-case
          Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input  files.   (-i  is
          specified by POSIX.)ions in both the PATTERN and the input  files.   (-i  is
          specified by POSIX.)
   -v, --invert-match
          Invert  the  sense  of  matching,  to  select  non-matching  lines.   (-v is
          specified by POSIX.)of  matching,  to  select  non-matching  lines.   (-v is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head, use `grep -Fiv -f file2.txt < file1.txt`.

`-F no regexps (fast)`

`-i case-insensitive`

`-v invert results`

`-f <pattern file> get patterns from file`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -iv -f file2 file1
bbbb
eeee
```

or you can use awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ a[tolower($1)]=$1; next }
{
  s=tolower($1)
  f=0
  for(i in a){if(i==s){f=1}}
  if(!f) { print s }
} ' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

ghostdog74's awk example can be simplified:

```
awk '
    FNR == NR { omit[tolower($0)]++; next }
    tolower($0) in omit {next}
    {print}
' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

For various set operations on files see:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html#sets

In your case the inputs are not sorted, so
you want the difference like:

```
sort -f file1 file1 file2 | uniq -iu
```